# Store comment (annotations) in mysql database using annotator js

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdf, annotations

I am using "annotator js" for comment on PDF files. All working fine.
Now i want to store comment (annotations) on Mysql Database.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [MVCE]. I suggest reading [ask].

Comment: Well,  I will have different users creating annotations across the same set of pages. I would want to show them only those annotations that they have annotated.  Each user will have their own account on the website. So, they can only annotate once they are logged in to their account. Thus, I also know their userID or loginID. So, I can associate the annotations that they create with their userID/loginID and thus, when they revisit the pages back I can show only their created annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using,this request
var annotation = $('#content').annotator();
  setTimeout(function(){

```
    annotation.annotator('addPlugin', 'Store', {
    prefix: prefixUrl,
      annotationData: {
        'uri': '/annotations'
      },

    urls: {
        create:  '/highlighter?page_id='+id,
        update:  '/update',
        destroy: '/delete',
        search:  '/annotations?page_id='+id
    }
  });
}
```